# Using iteration and recursive with asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, promise, jquery-deferred

I have an array I want to iterate and, based on its length, make an async call to obtain some data I want to add to a new array.

The pseudocode looks like:

```
var path =["Cars", "Owners", "Name"];
var parentObject = mainObject;

getChildren (path, parentObject){
    var deferred = new JQuery.Deferred();
    var pathSplit = path.split(".");
    var nestedObjectName = pathSplit[0];
    var childrenIds = new Array();
    if (pathSplit.length = 2){
        return deferred.resolve(parentObject.Id);
    }
    else{
        nestedObject = parentObject[nestedObjectName];
        pathSplit.shift();
        var promises = [];
        for (child in nestedObjects.children){                      //iteration
            promises.push(
                asyncCalltoGetDetails(child).then{ //After this line, the promises array resolves. !?!?!
                    getChildren(pathSplit, child).then(function(childId){   //recursivity
                        childrenIds.push(childId);
                    });     
                }           
            );
        }
        JQuery.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(){
            return deferred.resolve(childrenIds);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

When I make an iteration using an async call I use promises[] as explained here: [How do you work with an array of jQuery Deferreds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds)

And when I use a recursive call using an async method I used a deferred object pass all the through way. As explained here: [AngularJS, promise with recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607313/angularjs-promise-with-recursive-function)

The problem I have is that promises resolve when the asyncCalltoGetDetails is made, but I want to resolve it when the recursive getChildren return the deferred.resolve();

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? How to use properly the technique of promises[] and deferred object iterated in the same method?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `var path = {"Cars", "Owners", "Name"};` This is not a valid object

Comment: @A.Wolff. updated. Is just pseudocode to sumarize my actual code.

Comment: It's quite hard to figure out what you are doing here but have you tried setting array `promises` outside of `getChildren()` method? Here, each time you recall getChildren(), `promises` is a new array

Comment: Recursion can be regarded as a "vertical pyramid of doom" and should, IMHO, be avoided. In general, this kind of problem can be solved by dynamically building a `.then()` chain. This is typically not difficult but requires a different mid-set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem I have is that promises resolve when the asyncCalltoGetDetails is made, but I want to resolve it when the recursive getChildren return the deferred.resolve();

You're abusing the `deferred` a little, but it should work. If the promise resolves before `asyncCalltoGetDetails` has done its work, you need to search for the error in that function.

> Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

It might be only your pseudocode, but this looks buggy:

```
promises.push(
    asyncCalltoGetDetails(child).then{ //After this line, the promises array resolves. !?!?!
        getChildren(pathSplit, child).then(function(childId){   //recursivity
            childrenIds.push(childId);
        });     
    }           
);
```

`then` does expect a function, so I guess you gave it a function expression. Which line did you mean then - the `then` executing but not its callback, the callback executing but not waiting for `getChildren`?

For the latter the solution is that `then`, when used for chaining of action (composing promise plus callback to a new promise) allows you to return a promise from the callback. That's what's missing here - the `return` statement! If you just call `getChildren`, its result will never be used anywhere, the callback just returns `undefined`.

---

Also, for properly using promises, this is ugly:

```
    JQuery.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(){
        return deferred.resolve(childrenIds);
    });
}
return deferred.promise();
```

Stop using the "helper" array `childrenIds` (from the async callbacks)! Stop creating that `deferred` manually - you're not even rejecting it! Instead, make the children ids the *result values* of the promises, and use the arguments of your then-callbacks *only*.

Check my answers to [Understanding promises in node.js for recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18904745/1048572) and [Is there an example of using raw Q promise library with node to recursively traverse a directory asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19362009/1048572) - even though they're not using jQuery's implementation, they should give you an idea of how to do it.