# Clearing previous dragged file entries?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, promise

I have the following script that I want to use for uploading files. It's working fine, however I'm having trouble trying to find out why every time I upload a new file the previous file that was dragged is also present. Due to the asynchronous nature of the program I'm having trouble debugging this.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tekky/PYTBw/

Code:

```
var dndbox = $(".dndbox")[0];

dndbox.addEventListener("dragenter", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
},false);

dndbox.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
},false);

dndbox.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    var itemList = e.dataTransfer.items;

    var fp = [];

    var traverse = function(entry)
        {
            if (entry.isFile) {
                entry.file(function(file) {
                    var filepromise = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                        res(file);
                    });
                    fp.push(filepromise);
                });
            } else if (entry.isDirectory){
                var dR = entry.createReader();
                dR.readEntries(function(entries) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
                    {
                        traverse(entries[i]);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        var collection = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++) {
            var e = itemList[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
            var tp = new Promise(function(r, rj) {
                traverse(e);
                r(fp);
            });
            collection.push(tp);
        }

        Promise.all(collection).then(function(ff) {
            $(".prompt").show();
            $(".prompt").on("click", function() {
                $(this).hide();
                ff.forEach(function(pa) {
                    pa.forEach(function(p){
                        p.then(function(f)
                        {
                            console.log(f);
                        });

                    });
                });
            });
        });
},false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time I upload a new file the previous file that was dragged is also present.

This is not due to the asynchronous nature of `traverse` and has not much to do with the promises. It's due to this structure:

```
// left away some irrelevant callbacks
dndbox.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    var fp = [];
    // add entries to fp
    $(".prompt").on("click", function() {
        console.log(fp);
    });
}, false);
```

As you can see, every time something is dropped you create a new list and add a listener to the (same) element that *on every click from now on* will log that list. To solve that problem, you can:

- use only one global list that will be overwritten in case of a new drop event
- create a new `.prompt` element for each list to log
- uninstall the listener when it has fired so that it will no be triggered again. You can use the jQuery [`.one()` method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for that.

---

Apart from that, you are using Promises very oddly (not to say, wrong). `collection` is a list of promises that are immediately resolved with the still empty `fp` array. You only are lucky that all the files are read in when the `click` callback is triggered. Still, each `pa` you're getting `=== fp`, so that you are logging each item in `fp` as many times as `itemList` was long.

Have a look at [Understanding promises in node.js for recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18904745/1048572) and [Is there an example of using raw Q promise library with node to recursively traverse a directory asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19362009/1048572) for how to do it properly. In your case, it would be like

```
function traverse(entries)
    var collection = [];
    for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        if (entry.isFile) {
            collection.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                entry.file(res);
            }));
        } else if (entry.isDirectory){
            collection.push(new Promise(function(res, rej) {
                var dR = entry.createReader();
                dR.readEntries(res);
            }).then(traverse));
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(collection).then(function(results) { // flatten
        return [].concat.apply([], results);
    });
}

var entries = [];
for(var i = 0; i < itemList.length; i++)
    entries[i] = itemList[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

traverse(entries).then(function(fp) {
    $(".prompt").show().one("click", function() {
        $(this).hide();
        fp.forEach(console.log, console);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow... thank you. That looks like one big headache. I understand it but I feel like it would have taken me a long time to figure it out. I guess I just need to get used to using promises. This is the first time I've needed so many of them. I wish I could tip you a drink with some Bitcoin/Dogecoin or something! Again, thank you very much!